# Parse error CSS valid

Tags: css, media-queries

[ERRORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0Fi6.png)

```css
@media only screen (min-width: 1021px) and (max-width: 1180px) {
 
 .twee img {
  margin-top: 3em;
 }
 
 .drie {
  margin-top: 3em;
 }
 
 .audiovisual iframe {
  width: 90%;
 }
 
 .cp img {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0;
 }
}

@media only screen (min-width: 791px) and (max-width: 1020px) {
 body {
  background-image: url(IMG/Sam-open-copy-1020.jpg);
 }
 
 .twee img {
  margin-top: 7em;
 }
 
 .drie {
  margin-top: 7em;
 }
 
 .zes {
  margin-top: 2em; 
 }
  
 .audiovisual iframe {
  width: 90%;
 }
 
 .kaart iframe {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
 }
 
 .cp img {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0;
 }
 
 #totop {
  right: 0;
 }
}
```

So this is my code, my mediaqueries won't apply on my HTML.

When I validate I got these errors.(see the image ERRORS) But I can't find out what's wrong with it? I checked everything but probably I can't find it because I look over it or something....

Comment: And please add quotes to your background-image url() :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra 'and' in your @media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1021px) and (max-width: 1180px) { ...
```

Comment: You're welcome :) Can you mark this as answer? Dank!